# Python Wont go back to a previous loop (Zork)

Tags: python, python-3.x, while-loop

The code that i have been trying to fix is a zork program made in python however, when i try to loop back to another code it justs quits with no error into default idle. Please try my code out i really need help with this problem. It happens when you run these commands.
go north
go north
open window
enter window
go east
move rug
go down
go up.

The code thats not working is in the underground entrance section.

```
 #This sets the commands to be used
inv_command = ["inv", "inventory", "i"]
west = ["west", "w", "go west", "walk west"]
east = ["east", "e", "go east", "walk east"]
north = ["north", "n", "go north", "walk north"]
south = ["south", "s", "go south", "walk south"]
northeast = ["northeast", "ne", "go northeast", "walk northeast"]
northwest = ["northwest", "nw", "go northwest", "walk northwest"]
southeast = ["southeast", "se", "go southeast", "walk southeast"]
southwest = ["southwest", "sw", "go southwest", "walk southwest"]
up = ["up", "u", "go up", "go up stairs", "go up ladder", "up stairs", "up ladder"]
down = ["down", "d", "go down", "go down stairs", "go down ladder", "down stairs", "down ladder"]
take = ["take", "t"]

#This sets the objects
mailbox = 1
house_window = 0
house_bag = 0
knife = 0
lamp = 0
carpet = 0
rug = 0
light = 0
#This sets the inventory
class Item(object):
    def __init__(self, name, attack, armour):
        self.name = name
        self.attack = attack
        self.armour = armour

class Inventory(object):    
    def __init__(self):
        self.items = {}

    def add_item(self, item):
        self.items[item.name] = item

    def contain_item(self, item):
        self.items["Leaflet"] = item

    def print_items(self):
        print('\t'.join(['Name', 'Atk', 'Arm']))
        for item in self.items.values():
            print('\t'.join([str(x) for x in [item.name, item.attack, item.armour]]))
inventory = Inventory()

#This is the spawn area
import string
loop = 1
while loop == 1:
    inp = input("You wake up in a field surrounded by trees. The only pathway is going north \n>")
    if inp in north:
        loop = 2
    elif inp in inv_command:
        inventory.print_items()
    else:
        print("<You can't do that>")

    #This is the front of the house
    while loop == 2:
        inp = input("You face the front of a house. The windows are boarded up and the door is closed. In front there is a mailbox, and pathways leading west and further north\n>")
        if inp in south:
            loop = 1
        elif inp in inv_command:
            inventory.print_items()
        elif inp in north:
            loop = 3
        elif inp in west:
            loop = 4  
        elif inp in "open door":
            print("<The door is locked>")
        elif inp in "open window":
            print("<The windows can't be opened. They seem to be nailed shut>")
        elif inp in "read leaflet":
            if inventory.contain_item:
                print("<Welcome to the text based adventure!>")
                print("<When typing commands, please don't use capital letters.>")
                print("<have fun!>")
            else:
                print("<You don't have a leaflet>")
        elif inp in "open mailbox":
            if mailbox == 1:
                print("<The mailbox contains a leaflet>")
            else:
                print("<The mailbox is empty>")
        elif inp in "take leaflet":
            if mailbox == 1:
                inventory.add_item(Item('Leaflet', 0, 0))
                mailbox = 0
                print("<You have taken the leaflet>")
            else:
                print("<There's no leaflet in the mailbox>")   
        else:
            print("<You can't do that>")

        #This is the back of the house
        while loop == 3:
            inp = input("You face the back of the house, which has nothing except one ajar window. There is another pathway heading east \n>")
            if inp in inv_command:
                inventory.print_items()
            if inp in south:
                loop = 2
            if inp in "open window":
                house_window = 1
                print("<You opened the window enough for you to enter through>")
            if inp in "enter window":
                if house_window == 1:
                    loop = 5
                else:
                    print("<The window isn't opened enough to fit through>")
            else:
                print("<You can't do that>")

            #This is the kitchen
            while loop == 5:
                inp = input("You are inside the kitchen of the house. On the table there is a bag, there is a staircase leading up stairs and to the east there is a living room \n>")
                if inp in inv_command:
                    inventory.print_items()
                elif inp in "read manual":
                    if inventory.contain_item:
                        print("<Commands - inventory, take, open, attack>")
                        print("<Moving commands - go north, go south, go northeast, go northwest, go southeast, go southwest, up, down.>")
                        print("<Good luck!>")
                elif inp in up:
                    loop = 9
                elif inp in east:
                    loop = 8
                elif inp in "exit window":
                    loop = 3
                elif inp == "open bag":
                    print("<The bag contains a manual>")
                elif inp == "take bag":
                    print("<You would much rather take what's inside the bag then the bag itself>")
                elif inp == "take manual":
                    if house_bag == 0:
                        print("<You took the manual>")
                        house_bag = 1
                        inventory.add_item(Item('manual', 0, 0))
                    else:
                        print("<You have already taken the manual>")
                else:
                    print("<You can't do that>")
                #This is the living room
                while loop == 8:
                    if rug == 0:
                        inp = input("You are in the living room and you see a rug on the floor.\n>" )
                    if rug == 1:
                        inp = input("You are in the living room and you can see a trap door.\n>")
                    if inp == "move rug":
                        rug = 1
                        print("<You have found a trap door to the basement>")
                    if inp in down:
                        loop = 11
                    if inp in inv_command:
                         inventory.print_items()
                else:
                    print("<You can't do that>")

                #This is the Attic of the house
                while loop == 9:
                    if knife == 0:
                        if lamp == 0:
                            inp = input("You are in the attic, you can see a lamp and a knife. You see blood stains and stairs downwards \n>")
                        else:
                            inp = input("You are in the attic, you can see a knife. You see blood stains and stairs downwards \n>")
                    elif knife == 1:
                        if lamp == 0:
                            inp = input("You are in the attic, you can see a lamp. You see blood stains and stairs downwards \n>")
                        else:
                            inp = input("You are in the attic. You see blood stains and stairs downwards \n>")
                    if inp in inv_command:
                        inventory.print_items()
                    elif inp in down:
                        loop = 5

                    elif inp in "take knife":
                        if knife == 0:
                            print("You pulled the knife out from the wall and put it in your pocket")
                            print("<You have obtain a knife>")
                            knife = 1
                            inventory.add_item(Item('knife', 3, 0))
                        else:
                            print("<You have already taken the knife>")
                    elif inp in "take lamp":
                        if lamp == 0:
                            print("<You have taken the lamp>")
                            lamp = 1
                            inventory.add_item(Item('lamp', 0,0))
                        else:
                            print("<You have already taken the lamp>")
                    else:
                        print("<You can't do that>")
                #This is the underground entrance
                while loop == 11:
                    if lamp == 1:
                        if light == 0:
                            inp = input("It is dark, you can't see anything.\n>")
                            if inp in up:
                                loop = 8
                            if inp in inv_command:
                                inventory.print_items()
                            if inp == "turn on lamp" or "turn lamp on":
                                print("<You turned on the lamp>")
                                light = 1
                        if light == 1:
                            inp = input("You are below the living room, where you can see a entrance to a underground tunnel north of you.\n>")
                            if inp in up:
                                loop = 8
                            if inp in inv_command:
                                inventory.print_items()
                            if inp in north:
                                loop = 12
                    if lamp == 0:
                        inp = input("It is dark, you can't see anything you need to find a lamp.\n>")
                        if inp in up:
                            loop = 8
                        if inp in inv_command:
                            inventory.print_items()
                    else:
                        print("<You can't do that>")



        #This is the west forest entrance
        while loop == 4:
            inp = input("You are now in a dense forest. There is a fork in the road going NorthWest and SouthWest \n>")
            if inp in inv_command:
                inventory.print_items()
            elif inp in east:
                loop = 2
            elif inp in northwest:
                loop = 6
            elif inp in southwest:
                loop = 7
            else:
                print("<You can't do that>")
```

Comment: I roughly think if inp == "turn on lamp" or inp == "turn lamp on": should be the right way

Comment: sweet christmas... read about refactoring, there are plenty of good books on the subject, you'll thank me later. Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you're running into here is that you're trying to express a data structure (the way that locations are connected together) as program structure (a bunch of `while` loops), and that doesn't work out very well.

There's exactly one loop that should exist in this program, and it's a very simple one -- I'll express it in pseudocode:

```
while the game is still running:
    get a command
    perform that command
```

Properties of the *game state* -- including where the player is located -- should be stored as variables; information about those locations should be stored as objects. (For instance: Consider having a `Room` object, with one instance for each location, and standard properties like its description and contents.) This will allow you to structure your program in a much more sensible, and less repetitive, fashion.

Comment: thank you i will try to fix it but could you convert some code to show me how it should bw structured

Answer (score 0):

The issue you have is that your `loop` variable, which tracks the location is set to an unsupported value (10) when there's a down command in the living room.

```
#This is the living room
while loop == 8:
    if rug == 0:
        inp = input("You are in the living room and you see a rug on the floor.\n>" )
    if rug == 1:
        inp = input("You are in the living room and you can see a trap door.\n>")
    if inp in down:
        loop = 10
```

It is difficult to navigate your code, but we can search for the string `while loop ==` to see which rooms are handled:

```
Line 50: while loop == 1:
Line 60:     while loop == 2:
Line 97:         while loop == 3:
Line 115:             while loop == 5:
Line 144:                 while loop == 8:
Line 162:                 while loop == 9:
Line 196:                 while loop == 11:
Line 227:         while loop == 4:
```

So if `loop` is equal to 10, then none of these `while` statements will be true, so the code will finish running. You might want to put a line at the end of your program printing the game state for occasions such as these.

Looking at the code from line 196 onwards, that is the correct location of the underground entrance, so if you change Line 196 to `while loop == 10:` that should fix your immediate problem.

However it will help you in the long run if you reorganise and refactor your code. Or perhaps consider a more apt platform like [Inform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inform) or [TADS](http://www.tads.org/).

**EDIT:** Following your changes to fix the above issue, there's still a problem going north from the underground chamber. `loop` is set to `12`, but there's no such room defined. To check for all of these room transitions and events you can search for `loop =`:

```
Line 49: loop = 1
Line 50: while loop == 1:
Line 53:         loop = 2
Line 60:     while loop == 2:
Line 63:             loop = 1
Line 67:             loop = 3
Line 69:             loop = 4  
Line 97:         while loop == 3:
Line 102:                 loop = 2
Line 108:                     loop = 5
Line 115:             while loop == 5:
Line 125:                     loop = 9
Line 127:                     loop = 8
Line 129:                     loop = 3
Line 144:                 while loop == 8:
Line 153:                         loop = 11
Line 160:                 while loop == 9:
Line 174:                         loop = 5
Line 194:                 while loop == 11:
Line 199:                                 loop = 8
Line 208:                                 loop = 8
Line 212:                                 loop = 12
Line 216:                             loop = 8
Line 225:         while loop == 4:
Line 230:                 loop = 2
Line 232:                 loop = 6
Line 234:                 loop = 7
```

Comment: I would like to thank you however, if you remove that the loop back to the living room does not work at all

Comment: The if you are in the underground tunnel and try to go backup it brakes and leaves then program with no error thats the thing i need help with however, i did not see this mistake in my code so thank you for that.